# How to convert string column type to integer using Laravel migration?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to alter the column datatype using Laravel migration. But I am facing following error. Please help me out.

```
Schema::table('files', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('app_id')->change();
    $table->index(['app_id', 'filename']);
});
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE files CHANGE app_id app_id INT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel migrations change a column type from varchar to longText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724150/laravel-migrations-change-a-column-type-from-varchar-to-longtext)

Comment: Not working for the following $table->integer('app_id')->change(); When I convert string to integer CHARACTER SET utf8 added automatically. How to remove this?

Comment: Do you have `doctrine/dbal` package in your laravel project?

Comment: Yes I have doctrine/dbal.

Comment: I don't think encoding is the problem here. Also, why 2 times `app_id` in `ALTER TABLE files CHANGE app_id app_id INT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`?

Comment: That's not a problem. The script has generated like that only. I just copy pasted the error. If I run as ALTER TABLE files CHANGE app_id app_id INT  DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci` it is working in command line terminal. Note: If I removed the CHARACTER SET utf8 then it was worked.

Comment: Ok. Does this thread help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585182/laravel-3-schema-table-column-collation

Comment: Or this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/defining-column-collation-in-migrations?page=1

Comment: Finally I used DB::statement('ALTER TABLE files CHANGE app_id app_id INT DEFAULT 0 COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`); But no luck with $table->integer('app_id')->change();

Comment: I will see if I can reproduce this issue at my home. Also, is this with a fresh laravel installation or did you change anything in `config/database.php`?

Comment: I didn't change anything. It is a fresh installation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your issue is most likely caused by a bug in the most recent version of the `doctrine/dbal` package. The issue was introduced with `v2.10.0`.

You can always downgrade the package in your `composer.json` to `v2.9.3` it should work just fine.

See the offical issue here:  https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3714

Comment: Wow, I wasted hours on this before I finally found your post. Laravel and Doctrine each have been blaming each other. It's still not resolved. I'll just ignore for now. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30539#issuecomment-559605145

Answer (score 14):

As a alternative solution to https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3714 that is downgrading the doctrine/dbal package u can do:

```
Schema::table('member_section', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('type')->charset(null)->collation(null)->change();
});
```